# Are all promises created equal?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

Consider the following code:

```
var someFunc = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(37);
      }, 1000);
  });
};

var f1 = function() {
  return someFunc()
    .then(val => {
      return val + 1;
    });  
}

var f2 = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    someFunc()
    .then(val => {
      resolve(val + 1);
    });    
  });
}

var f3 = function() {
  someFunc().then(val => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(val + 1);
      });    
  });              
};
```

`Angular 6` change detection fails to kick in if a bound variable's value is updated in the `then` of f1.

So, if the following is a click handler:

**This doesn't work: (UI does not get updated)**

```
public myClickHandler() {
   f1().then(val => this.uiBoundVar = val);
}
```

**This works: (UI gets updated)**

```
public myClickHandler() {
   f2().then(val => this.uiBoundVar = val);
   // This works too
   // f3().then(val => this.uiBoundVar = val);
}
```

Not sure if it's because of: [From MDN Promise return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value)

> A Promise in the pending status. The handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) then gets called asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty). After the invocation of the handler function, if the handler function:
>
> returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value;

Comment: "Angular 6 change detection fails to kick in if a bound variable's value is updated in the then of f1." This sounds like a bug.

Comment: I was so wrong about my previous comment... and I tested it here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcz1au?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. It works as desired, can you share your dependencies? I checked in angular 6.

Comment: I doubt the `f3()` version works, surely you'd get a `f3(...) is undefined; can't access its "then" property`